# Check wreq request headers

Tags: haskell

I am pretty new to Haskell and I am not sure how I can achieve this. I am using [wreq](http://www.serpentine.com/wreq/) as HTTP client and I would like to check what HTTP headers are being sent to the server. For instance, I have defined the following method, which tries to authenticate using Facebook credentials:

```
authenticate ⦂ String → String → IO (Response ByteString)
authenticate facebookId facebookToken =
    postWith opts "https://api.somedomain.com/auth" (object $ ["facebook_token" .= facebookToken, "facebook_id" .= facebookId])
      where opts = defaults & header "Content-Type" .~ ["application/json"]
                            & header "Accept" .~ ["application/json"]
                            & proxy ?~ httpProxy "localhost" 9396
```

With POSTman I get the proper response but with `wreq` I get forbidden access (403). I assume some extra request headers might be added by the library and that's what I would like to check.

Any hints?

EDIT: An http proxy is now being used to check HTTP traffic (`wreq` requests are not detected though).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Wreq, the `Options` type is an instance of `Show`, so you can pass it to [`print`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Prelude.html#v:print), or simply inspect it on ghci:

```
ghci> import Network.Wreq
ghci> defaults :: Options
Options { manager = Left _, proxy = Nothing, auth = Nothing, headers = 
[("User-Agent","haskell wreq-0.3.0.1")], params = [], redirects = 10, cookies = [] }
```

You can also use the [`headers`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/wreq-0.3.0.1/docs/Network-Wreq.html#v:headers) lens to focus directly on the headers:

```
ghci> defaults ^. headers
[("User-Agent","haskell wreq-0.3.0.1")]
```

But if Wreq is adding some headers *after* passing the options to `postWith`, you'll have to use a web debugging proxy like [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to know what's going on.

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to use a web proxy without much success, requests triggered with `wreq` are not detected. See updated question. Any ideas?

Comment: Finally it was an unrelated issue (`https` requests are not directly monitored).

Comment: For future reference, you can use http://httpbin.org/ to check these things. It's really excellent.